# Docker compose will not pull all images from compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker with docker-compose.yml file.
There I put two different services inside, which I'd like to update.
Moreover I ran portainer and added also some other services there:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/docker $ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                   PORTS                                                                                                                             NAMES
ec830e789d38   nodered/node-red:latest   "npm --no-update-not…"   8 days ago     Up 6 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:1880->1880/tcp, :::1880->1880/tcp                                                                                         docker_node-red_1
15aa942b2b94   openhab/openhab:3.1.1     "/entrypoint gosu op…"   8 days ago     Up 8 days (healthy)                                                                                                                                        docker_openhab_1
e805e3f527c4   portainer/portainer-ce    "/portainer"             8 days ago     Up 8 days                0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9443->9443/tcp, :::9443->9443/tcp   portainer
80990d1ad7e7   influxdb:latest           "/entrypoint.sh infl…"   9 months ago   Up 8 days                                                                                                                                                  InfluxDB
```

My actual docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/docker $ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "2"

services:
  openhab:
    image: "openhab/openhab:3.1.1"
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "./openhab_addons:/openhab/addons"
      - "./openhab_conf:/openhab/conf"
      - "./openhab_userdata:/openhab/userdata"
    environment:
      USER_ID: "1000"
      GROUP_ID: "1000"
      OPENHAB_HTTP_PORT: "8080"
      OPENHAB_HTTPS_PORT: "8443"
      EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS: "-Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin"


services:
  node-red:
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    networks:
      - node-red-net
    volumes:
      - node-red-data:/data
    devices:
      - "/dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0"
volumes:
  node-red-data:

networks:
  node-red-net:
```

In order to update the openhab container from 3.1.1 to 3.2.0, I changed the image name inside compose file to openhab/openhab:3.2.0.

Afterwards I started docker-compose pull and the system only checked if there is a new image for node-red available. But not for openhab.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all the services under a single services key. That's also why it's plural.

```yaml
services:
  openhab:
    ...
  node-red:
    ...
```